# MySQL Cursor with a variable in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, cursor

I've the following code in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare v_degree int(11);
declare v_start_age smallint(6);
declare v_end_age smallint(6);
declare v_gender varchar(20);
declare v_calctable varchar(200);

SELECT calculationtable into v_calctable FROM wac.degrees where tablename = concat("cdb_" + arg_tablename);

declare cur CURSOR for select degree, start_age, end_age, belt, gender from v_calctable;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
```

Like this I'll get a syntax error in the line "SELECT calculationtable into v_calctable FROM wac.degrees where tablename = concat("cdb_" + arg_tablename);"

If I put it after the "Declare cursor" there's no syntax error, but I need the result to be used on de Cursor select statement.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you probably need is just a JOIN and not a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `my_procedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare v_degree int(11);
declare v_start_age smallint(6);
declare v_end_age smallint(6);
declare v_gender varchar(20);
declare v_calctable varchar(200);

SELECT calculationtable into v_calctable FROM wac.degrees where tablename = concat("cdb_" + arg_tablename);
begin                                                                   -- write here begin keyword
declare cur CURSOR for select degree, start_age, end_age, belt, gender from v_calctable;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
end;                                                                    -- end here inner block

END
```

when you use inner block by another **begin** and **end** keyword 
then it have no syntask error .
but this procedure give you correct result or not i am not clear